# JVM memory mapping over a Linux Process

Tags: java, process, operating-system, jvm, virtual-machine

I am trying to understand how JVM's memory maps to that of the underlying Linux process.

Here is my understanding of JVM's memory architecture:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38889378/jvm_arch.jpg

Now the next diagram shows the mapping of memory when a JVM instance is scheduled over a Linux process.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38889378/OS_Process.jpg

Here I have taken the following assumptions:

1. **The JVM Stack is actually part of the Linux Process HEAP**, and hence we can say all Java user program is held over the Linus Process HEAP.
2. **Linux Process Stack is used for Native Stack and also used by JVM's internal native procedure calls**.

Please help me figure out if my assumptions are correct.

Please excuse me for putting up Image URL's, I don't have enough reputation to have them embedded. I am a new user, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your Linux image cannot be completely correct. When using JNI, one can make use of both the stack and heap of the host process from within a jclass method. There is some overlap.
Though i expect you're safe in the assumption that the old, new, and permanent generations are all stored in the heap.

Comment: @Knetic Thanks for the answer, but how about the Java Stack and Program Counter, I assume that is also part of the Linux Process Heap. Is my assumption good on this.