# Memory details of JVM as a process

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, operating-system

I'm new to this topic, so, apologies if my question is obvious but here it is-
Whenever we start a Java application, a new instance of JVM is created. JVM itself is a process which runs on OS and like any other process, it has memory requirements of its own.
I'm aware of heap and non-heap memory structure and how they can be configured and manipulated. What I'm looking for is memory details of jvm process itself, 
**How the overall memory is divided** i.e. jvm's own memory requirements+heap+non-heap+native stack
How many segments are there? 
How much memory OS allocates to JVM and how does jvm use it further?
Is there any command or utility to check these details while running an application?

I've googled a lot but not finding anything concrete in this direction, almost everywhere articles explain the heap and non-heap memory structure (eden / old / meta etc.). I've also visited below links-
[JVM Memory Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290787/jvm-memory-types)
[How is the java memory pool divided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided)
[JVM Memory segments allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521793/jvm-memory-segments-allocation)
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/
[JVM memory mapping over a Linux Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745044/jvm-memory-mapping-over-a-linux-process)
[Understanding JVM Memory Allocation and Java Out of Memory: Heap Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272877/understanding-jvm-memory-allocation-and-java-out-of-memory-heap-space)
It seems I'm stuck here, any pointer on this topic would be great so that I can start looking in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native Memory Tracking (NMT) feature of Java 8 helps to answer your questions.

Run Java with the option `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary`
Then at run time execute the following command to print JVM memory statistics:

```
jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory summary
```

The output will look like:

```
Total:  reserved=664192KB,  committed=253120KB

-                 Java Heap (reserved=516096KB, committed=204800KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=516096KB, committed=204800KB)

-                     Class (reserved=6568KB, committed=4140KB)
                            (classes #665)
                            (malloc=424KB, #1000)
                            (mmap: reserved=6144KB, committed=3716KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=6868KB, committed=6868KB)
                            (thread #15)
                            (stack: reserved=6780KB, committed=6780KB)
                            (malloc=27KB, #66)
                            (arena=61KB, #30)

-                      Code (reserved=102414KB, committed=6314KB)
                            (malloc=2574KB, #74316)
                            (mmap: reserved=99840KB, committed=3740KB)

-                        GC (reserved=26154KB, committed=24938KB)
                            (malloc=486KB, #110)
                            (mmap: reserved=25668KB, committed=24452KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=106KB, committed=106KB)
                            (malloc=7KB, #90)
                            (arena=99KB, #3)

-                  Internal (reserved=586KB, committed=554KB)
                            (malloc=554KB, #1677)
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=0KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=906KB, committed=906KB)
                            (malloc=514KB, #2736)
                            (arena=392KB, #1)

-           Memory Tracking (reserved=3184KB, committed=3184KB)
                            (malloc=3184KB, #300)

-        Pooled Free Chunks (reserved=1276KB, committed=1276KB)
                            (malloc=1276KB)

-                   Unknown (reserved=33KB, committed=33KB)
                            (arena=33KB, #1)
```

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for command line utilities start from `jps` that just prints PIDs of all running java processes. Then choose one that you want to discover and use `jmap` with its PID.

JDK arrives with visual tools also. The old one `JConsoke` and the newer and better one `VisualVM`.

Comment: I've used Jconsole and Visual VM. Just found this article, I'm looking something like this, http://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2011/06/taking-a-closer-look-at-sizing-the-java-process.html

Comment: If OS allocated X memory to JVM as a process, then out of X, JVM will allocate memory to heap / perm based on -Xms / -Xmx / -XX:PermSize, MaxPermSize, let's say remaining memory is (X1 = X-heap-perm). Now what happens with X1, how much memory does JVM need for itself out of X1, how much goes to other segments? as the article explains there are few other segments also